# How can I generate a link to a nested resource?

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes, resources

The Laravel application I am working on has two resources.

The routes for the second resource are given below:

```
$ php artisan route:list | grep -i activity 

POST       | admin/procedure/{id}/activity                  | admin.procedure.{id}.activity.store   | (...)\ProcedureActivityController@store    
GET|HEAD   | admin/procedure/{id}/activity                  | admin.procedure.{id}.activity.index   | (...)\ProcedureActivityController@index    
GET|HEAD   | admin/procedure/{id}/activity/create           | admin.procedure.{id}.activity.create  | (...)\ProcedureActivityController@create   
GET|HEAD   | admin/procedure/{id}/activity/{activity}       | admin.procedure.{id}.activity.show    | (...)\ProcedureActivityController@show     
PUT|PATCH  | admin/procedure/{id}/activity/{activity}       | admin.procedure.{id}.activity.update  | (...)\ProcedureActivityController@update   
DELETE     | admin/procedure/{id}/activity/{activity}       | admin.procedure.{id}.activity.destroy | (...)\ProcedureActivityController@destroy  
GET|HEAD   | admin/procedure/{id}/activity/{activity}/edit  | admin.procedure.{id}.activity.edit    | (...)\ProcedureActivityController@edit
```

I call this setup a nested resource because activities are defined under a procedure. The definition or the routes looks like this:

```
Route::resource('procedure', 'ProcedureController');
Route::resource('procedure/{id}/activity', 'Admin\ProcedureActivityController');
```

I would like to generate a link to the POST action for a new activity that belongs to procedure 3 as I would with the list-all-procedures route;

```
$ php artisan tinker
>>> route('admin.procedure.index')
=> "http://localhost/admin/procedure"

>>> route('admin.procedure.{id}.activity')
InvalidArgumentException with message 
        'Route [admin.procedure.{id}.activity] not defined.'
```

Is there a way to generate a link to a nested resource using the standard helpers and facades?

Comment: FYI, https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route definition for the nested resource is not quite right.

```
Route::resource('procedure/{id}/activity', 'Admin\ProcedureActivityController');
```

Should be:

```
Route::resource('procedure.activity', 'Admin\ProcedureActivityController');
```

Also I am not sure how you are getting `{id}` in the URI as the ResourceRegistrar will create parameters based on the resource name. Based on the definition that should be `{procedure}` for your first resource definition.

You should end up with a route name like `admin.procedure.activity.index` for the index route.

`route('admin.procedure.activity.index', ['procedure' => $id]);`

[Laravel 5.1 - Controllers - Restful - Nested Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-nested-resources)

> `Route::resource('photos.comments', 'PhotoCommentController');`
>
> This route will register a "nested" resource that may be accessed with URLs like the following: `photos/{photos}/comments/{comments}`.

Comment: this works as well: route('admin.procedure.activity.show', [10, 20])

Comment: Yes you can pass them like that and they will be placed in the order you pass them :).  I have a habit of using associative array to make it clear and in case too many parameters were passed, it will add them as GET params to the url.

Comment: Http methods (GET, POST) and parameter format (url, formdata) are deducted from the route or even controller-method names in case of resource routes...

Answer (score 1):

You should use `route()` with a parameter to make it work:

```
route('admin.procedure.{id}.activity.index', $id);
```

Comment: >>> route('admin.procedure.{id}.activity', 22);
InvalidArgumentException with message 'Route [admin.procedure.{id}.activity] not defined.'

Comment: Sorry, I've copy-pasted route from you question and forgot to add `.index` to it. Please check updated answer.